# How do I troubleshoot a server I can't get logged into?

Tags: login, timeout, sql-server-2008-r2

This morning I am unable to log into SQL Server because it appears to be busy doing something, so much so that CPU usage is constantly at 98%-99%. I am guessing that something has gone wrong with the maintenance plan that ran over the weekend, but I can't get into the error logs see what is happening.

On logging in I keep getting messages like "insufficiently memory in the buffer pool" and "the server is not responding".

Is there any way I can figure out what is happening without logging onto to the server? Or some way I can squeeze in a login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try connection to it remotely with PowerShell.
This usually requires less resources then a full fledged RDP-session.

Example:

```
invoke-command -computername myServer -scriptblock {Get-Process}
```

This way you can get a look at what's running remotely and later on, kill it.

Comment: Let's hope that the remote servers powershell has been configured for remote execution. `winrm quickconfig` to the rescue!

Comment: Ah, yes, that is something we do on every install :).